# Iteration over a sub-list of dictionaries -Python

Tags: python

I have a list of dictionaries e.g.:

```
list_d = [{"a":1},{"b":2,"c":3}]
```

*(case 1)*

```
for item in list_d:
   # add values of each sub-list's dicts
```

*(case 2)*

```
for item in list_d[1]:
   # add values of the specific sub-list of dict
```

(case1) it returns the sum of each sub-list's dict values.

(case2) returns only the keys of the dictionaries.

Is there an efficient way to get the dictionaries of the sub-list(case2) so to add the values?

Comment: Please check your terminology; what do you mean by *sub-list*, an element perhaps? What do you mean by *adding*? What are the dictionaries of a dictionary? What is the expected result?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Yes , I meant the element of the list. So to rephrase, my question is: instead of iterating over the list and take the sum of each element , I was wondering whether I can get only the dict of the second element {"b":2,"c":3} and apply a function on the values of this dictionary, in this case to add its values (expected_result = 5) . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
reduce(lambda x,y: x + sum(y.values()), list_d, 0)
```

That is, starting with 0 (as the first `x`), add the sum of all values in each `dict` within `list_d`.

Here's another way:

```
sum(sum(x.values()) for x in list_d)
```

That is, sum the (sum of values for each `dict` in `list_d`).

Answer (score 0):

As Antti points out it is unclear what you are asking for. I would recommend you having a look at the built-in tools in Python for [Functional programming](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html)

Consider the following examples:

```
from operator import add

list_d = [{"a":1},{"b":2,"c":3}]

case_1 = map(lambda d: sum(d.values()), list_d)
case_2 = reduce(add, map(lambda d: sum(d.values()), list_d))
```